# Encoding error with sublime text 2 and Python

Tags: python, sublimetext2

After struggling with encoding problems in a rows-rich code in sublime text 2, I decided to make a simpler experiment. I used the following code, trying to print in Chinese :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print('你好')
```

When running in sublime text, I receive the following error:

```
File "D:\xampp\htdocs\stam\chinese print try.py", line 4, in <module>
print('\u4f60\u597d')
File "d:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: character           maps to <undefined>
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

**And here is the big but.** When I run the code through the regular Python GUI, everything's fine. It prints.

I tried looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166076/sublime-text-2-encoding-error-with-python3-build) but didn't understand how it can help me (which could indeed be my lack of understanding in sublime text configuration).

Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: It seems you're trying to print on a console that's using `cp1252` encoding. Is normal it yields an error since that encoding doesn't support chinese characters. You need to set a proper encoding for your console with `chcp` command.

Comment: Thanks @PauloBu, I tried to dig into that but it didn't find how to make it happen. Can I trouble you for directions?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to this [printing UTF-8 in Python 3 using Sublime Text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576308/printing-utf-8-in-python-3-using-sublime-text-3)

You can modify or add a new build and include "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf8"} in the build file.

For example, the new build file should look like the following (windows 7):

```
{
    "cmd": ["your_path\\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf8"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this: http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_765abd7b0101dtbw.html

I do these two things which finally solved this problem:

- In code, add`import sys
  reload(sys)
  sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")`
- in Python.sublime-build, add `"encoding":"utf-8"`