# Unicode Encode Error in Sublime Text 3 console

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, sublimetext3, sublime-anaconda

I’m always getting a

'UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf6' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)'

in the sublime text 3 console when trying to print a non-ascii character.
I'm using Anaconda Python Builder to build the system. Building the system with the built-in “python” runs perfectly (i.e. prints out non-ascii characters fine) and also running the script from the terminal works fine (i'm running the script on Mac OS Sierra).

I assume the problem must have something to do with the Anaconda Python Builder and I thought adding the default encoding to the Anaconda.sublime-settings might help, but it doesn’t :-( Here is my anaconda user settings file:

{
    "python_interpreter": "/usr/local/bin/python3.6",
    "anaconda_linting": false,
    "pep8": false,
    "default_encoding": "UTF-8"
}

I would very much appreciate if you could help me along in this matter as I’m searching for a solution for two days now without success :-(

Thank you!
Chris

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I found a way to do it:

- Install this plugin: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Environment%20Settings
- Change the user settings for that EnvironmentSettings plugin to look like this:

  {
      "env": {
          "Darwin": {
              "LC_ALL": "en_US.UTF-8"
          }
      }
  }

Comment: You do not even need an external plugin. You can also edit your build system, adding `"env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf8"}`. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39576308/2291710).