# sublime and bs4 error (windows 10)

Tags: python, sublimetext

I have created a virtualenv (i named it scrape), i activated it and i have installed packages and beautifulsoup4. I am trying to make sublime text 3 to work (ie show build results) within a virtualenv. I created a new build system like this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:/Users//User1/Desktop/scrape/Scripts/python.exe", "-u","$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Then i run this code (i know that Betfair has an API,but this is not the point here):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get("https://www.betfair.com/")

print(url.status_code)

bs_4 = BeautifulSoup(url.text, "html.parser")

print(bs_4.prettify())
```

When i run the above with Powershell and virualenv activated, i am getting "200" and then all the html data (ie as ti is supposed to be). When i run inside sublime text, i am only getting "200" inside the build results panel, with no any html data. The fact that i am getting "200" means that my build system works ok, but why aren't the html results shown? Note that i am not getting any error.

Now, if i change the url from https://betfair.com to  https://ubet.com.cy/sports (that contains some Greek characters), everything works ok if i do it in Powershell (ie i am getting "200" plus the html data.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get("https://ubet.com.cy/sports")

print(url.status_code)

bs_4 = BeautifulSoup(url.text, "html.parser")

print(bs_4.prettify())
```

If however i do it in sublime text, i am getting the "200" plus the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\scrape\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x93' in position 6074: character maps to <undefined>
```

This is line 19:

```
17class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
18    def encode(self, input, final=False):
19        return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
```

In general, what i am looking for is a solution to have sublime text to work like if i run python inside Powershell (as it looks that everytime i will be coming across a new error). Is there something you can help me with.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a Sublime Text specific problem. Sublime Text has this [`env` dictionary](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/exec.html#exec-command-arguments) that is going to update environment variables before executing Python.

> Dictionary of environment variables to be merged with the current process’ before passing them to cmd.
>
> Use this option, for example, to add or modify environment variables without modifying your system’s settings.

Go to Tools -> Build System -> New Build System and set the [`PYTHONIOENCODING`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) to `utf8`:

```
"env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf8"},
```

See more at:

- [printing UTF-8 in Python 3 using Sublime Text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576308/printing-utf-8-in-python-3-using-sublime-text-3)
- [Unicode Encode Error in Sublime Text 3 console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648808/unicode-encode-error-in-sublime-text-3-console)