# import utf-8 csv in python3.x - special german characters

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, import-csv

I have been trying to import a csv file containing special characters (ä ö ü)

in python 2.x all special characters where automatically encoded without need of specifying **econding** attribute in the open command.

I can´t figure out how to get this to work in **python 3.x**

```
import csv

f = open('sample_1.csv', 'rU', encoding='utf-8')
csv_f = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')

bla = list(csv_f)
print(type(bla))

print(bla[0])
print(bla[1])
print(bla[2])
print()
print(bla[3])
```

**Console output** (Sublime Build python3)

```
<class 'list'>
['\ufeffCat1', 'SEO Meta Text']
['Damen', 'Damen----']
['Damen', 'Damen-Accessoires-Beauty-Geschenk-Sets-']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/importer_tree.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(bla[3])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf6' in position 37: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**input sample_1.csv** (excel file saved as utf-8 csv)

```
Cat1;SEO Meta Text
Damen;Damen----
Damen;Damen-Accessoires-Beauty-Geschenk-Sets-
Damen;Damen-Accessoires-Beauty-Körperpflege-
Männer;Männer-Sport-Sportschuhe-Trekkingsandalen-
Männer;Männer-Sport-Sportschuhe-Wanderschuhe-
Männer;Männer-Sport-Sportschuhe--
```

1. is this only an output format issue or am I also importing the data
   wrongly?
2. how can I print out "Männer"?

thank you for your help/guidance!

Comment: The problem seems to be your *terminal* isn't configured to print unicode

Comment: So, check `import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)`

Comment: import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding) returns **US-ASCII**

Comment: So then definitely that's the problem. Is your local set for UTF-8?

Comment: thank you! in the terminal my stdout.encoding is set to 
**UTF-8** 
in fact the csv is imported correctly when launched through terminal.

only issue is when launching the build through **Sublime** (US-ASCII), is it possible to switch to utf-8 without messing up environment variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you to [juanpa-arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) and to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44088439/9059135

Issue is due to my Sublime settings:
`sys.stdout.encoding` returns **US-ASCII**

in the terminal same command returns **UTF-8**

Setting up the [Build system in Sublime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44088439/9059135) properly will solve the issue