# Ascii codec can't encode character error, content.decode('utf-8','ignore') won't work. Any other options?

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup, ascii, codec

Example code:

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs
import urllib
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import Request

req = Request("https://www.openbugbounty.org/researchers/Spam404/vip/page/1/", 
              headers ={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')
print(soup)
```

## My output gives me the following error:

File "/Users/student/Desktop/AutoBots/kbfza2.py", line 15, in 
    print(soup)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa0' in position 5194: ordinal not in range(128)

After searching for a solution online for a while, it seemed that changing my soup line to:

```
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce.decode('utf-8','ignore'),'lxml)
```

would solve this for me but this hasn't fixed anything for me.
Am I mistaken in thinking that the decode function with the ignore argument should allow me to `print(soup)` without error even if it isn't successfully decoded completely?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with the code you posted

Comment: What python version? What like give you that error?

Comment: Full error stack please. It's vital to know which component the error is coming from.

Comment: edited the post to include the full error stack: File "/Users/student/Desktop/AutoBots/kbfza2.py", line 15, in print(soup) UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa0' in position 5194: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 0):

Just re-read your question and I believe you are trying to print Unicode text to a console that doesn't support that character set (I couldn't reproduce the error with the code you posted).

You may need to force your console output to `utf-8` encoding, or if you are using an IDE like sublime text, [change it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576308/printing-utf-8-in-python-3-using-sublime-text-3) to render `utf-8` encoding.

Comment: The `#coding` trick only works against a certain class of errors, those where the bad character is part of your source code. It doesn't look relevant to this problem.

Comment: I edited my post to include the rest of the error message